# Logic Level Shifter 24/12 V to 3.3 V

Tags: esp8266, level-shifting, esp32, logic-level

I have a ESP32 and Industrial Sensor with voltage output 0-12 V and 0-24 V. How can I interface 2 logic levels with my 3.3 V ESP32? Can I use a BSS138 or do I need another module?

Comment: Is in the case that you want to convert, in one case, a 0-12 V sensor output to a 0-3.3 V signal compatible with your ESP32 I/O pins? And in another case, 0-24 V sensor output to a 0-3.3 V signal, as well?

Comment: @jonk yeah, I want to interface 2 logic levels with ESP32. WIth bss138 I can interface 3.3 volts with 5 volts, but I want to use it with 12 and 24-volt voltage level

Comment: How fast do these sensors change output values? Can you share the ground reference between your ESP32 and the sensors? Or do you perhaps need to use an opto-isolator? How much current can you draw from the sensor outputs when high? How much current can they sink when low?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest methods I can think of for getting your required signal levels are these:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flGPwG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The safest way (for digital signals only) is with an optocoupler:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2forOSF.png)</sup>

The optocouplers allow you to completely electrically isolate your own circuit from the industrial controller, which is why I included the dotted connection between the grounds of your controller and your own circuitry. It will work either way, but by omitting that connection you get the ultimate protection from an errant controller.

It may be tempting to connect the optocoupler transistor as an [emitter follower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_collector), to obtain a non-inverted signal without having to provide an additional inverting stage, but this is unreliable for 3.3V operation due to the base-emitter voltage drop of 0.7V. This can work for 5V systems though, so I include this for completeness only:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDbqn3.png)</sup>

You may use a transistor to perform digital level translation, but the output signal will be inverted with respect to the input. It beats the simple potential divider solution because it can work with any input voltage:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9HOES.png)</sup>

If you use the MOSFET solution, be sure to choose a device that can tolerate a 24V potential difference from gate to source. For example, The [2N7000](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nds7002a-d.pdf) cannot handle more than 20V difference, which is why I specified the [VN10K](https://datasheet.octopart.com/VN10KN3-G-Supertex-datasheet-43981.pdf) here.

Lastly, there are ICs dedicated to this kind of function, such as the [CD4504](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4504b-ep.pdf) level shifter IC. It won't work for 24V inputs, but for 12V signals it does a great job. Perhaps you can find a 24V compatible device to suit your needs.

Comment: Ok, Thank you, sir

Answer (score 1):

A BSS138 is a little outside your spec range as it only has a Vgs of 20V max.  You probably need to find a transistor with a slightly higher Vgs rating.

However, given that you said the word "industrial", I also hear the word "noise"--especially on your ground line.  :)

As such, I'd probably use an optoisolator for this if you can get away with it.  That way you don't have to worry about whether your ground reference is noisy.

If your signal is very slow, you could even use a relay for it.  However, an optoisolator is probably cheaper, faster, and smaller.

Good luck.

Comment: ok, thank you for your advice

Comment: Or you can have a voltage divider on the MOSFETs instead of driving the gate directly. You need to keep Vgs in check, but for mosfet to open you only need certain voltage difference. The thing is, without posting the schematic I cannot (and I doubt many can) give precise answer. If you showed what and how exactly you want to be hooked up, would have been easier. But I'm pretty certain you can get away with the MOSFET you're using if you throw in a pair of resistors here and there. But no schematic - no specifics.

Answer (score 0):

If these are analog signals to be sampled by ADC, you can use a resistor voltage divider.